# Cygwin ssh issue: Could not resolve hostname awshost1: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ssh, cygwin, alias

I'm learning "startup engineering", encountered this error when using ssh alias. Below is the detailed steps (executed in Cygwin windows 8):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ cp ~/downloads/skey.pem ~/.ssh/
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/skey.pem
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ nano ~/.ssh/config
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host awshost1
HostName ec2-54-218-35-71.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
User ubuntu
IdentityFile "~/.ssh/skey.pem"
```

Then I ran below command

```
ssh awshost1
```

But it prompts

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname awshost1: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

And the verbose output:

```
$ ssh -vv awshost
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname awshost: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

Would anyone please help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the output, your ssh-client reads `/etc/ssh_config`, not `~/.ssh/config`.
Try to connect like that: `ssh -F ~/.ssh/config awshost1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can run `ssh-host-config`

and place your ssh config in `/etc/ssh_config` which will make it work flawlessly